# Android On Screen Buttons overlap with Tabs Application

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, interface

I am building the layout of my App. It uses the default Tabs layout and the fragment is a Relative Layout with a GridLayout and a TableLayout in it. 
At the bottom of the Screen I have a View, which should be fixed to the bottom of the screen with android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" and the Preview shows the layout I intend. 
When I run the App in the Simulator the Android On Screen Buttons overlap and cover the lower Part of my App.

Preview:

[image: Android Studio Preview]

Simulator:

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp" >

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomView"
    android:id="@+id/spacer"/>

<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/bottomView"
    >


    <TextView
        android:text="Punkte ø"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp" />


    <TextView
        android:text="15.0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
    N<TextView
        android:text="Noten ø"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="1.0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24sp" />


    <TextView
        android:text="Anzahl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</GridLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_above="@id/spacer"
    android:id="@+id/red"
    >

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_above="@id/spacer"
    >


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="13"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="14"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"

    />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="15"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"

        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"

        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="11"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"

    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="12"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"

    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"

    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"

        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="9"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"

    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"

    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"

    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="6"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"

    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"

    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"

    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"

    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AC"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"

    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"

    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DEL"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"

    />

</GridLayout>

</TableLayout>

<TextView
    android:text="15  15  15  15  15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
```

How can I make the white bottom view stick to the botttom without being overlaped by the naviugation buttons?

Comment: probably your problem is  android:layout_height="65dp", try change to android:layout_height="wrap_content" and see what happens.

Comment: @Bruno I tried it. The only thing that happens is that the view on bottom is getting smaller, but the software navigation buttons still overlap the app.

Comment: and if you use linearlayout instead of relativelayout?

Answer (score 0):

Please replace with this code you can see perfect layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="15  15  15  15  15"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1" />


<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bottomView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Punkte ø"
        android:textSize="18sp" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="15.0"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Noten ø"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="1.0"
        android:textSize="24sp" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Anzahl"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="5"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</GridLayout>


<View
    android:id="@+id/spacer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottomView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/red"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView"
    android:layout_above="@id/spacer"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/spacer"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView"
        android:columnCount="3">


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="13"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="14"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="15"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="10"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="11"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="12"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="7"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="8"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="9"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="5"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="6"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="AC"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="DEL"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

            />

    </GridLayout>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it doesn't seem to fix the issue. What do you think is the problem and how did you try to fix it?

Comment: in My device android version Android M Run Perfect which android version you use i try after then i will help you.